# Counting quadratic curves in $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ passing through seven points in general position

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, enumerative-geometry

Let $p_1,\dots,p_7 \in \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ be 7 points in general position.
What is the number of maps $F=(F_0,F_1):\mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ modulo domain reparametrization for which $F_0$, $F_1$ are degree 2 and such that the image of $F$ passes through $p_1,\dots,p_7$?

Comment: Can you reduce to the case of $\mathbb P^2$ by blowing up one of your seven points and then blowing down the two lines through it and adding them to your list of points? I think this will preserve your genericity condition and then you're reduced to cubics on $\mathbb P^2$. If not, adapting the argument from cubics on $\mathbb P^2$ with elliptic curves should work.

Comment: By the "generalized Riemann-Hurwitz formula", the number of curves of geometric genus $0$ in a general pencil of $(2,2)$ divisors on $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ equals the (topological) Euler characteristic of the blowing up of $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ at the $8$ base points of the pencil, i.e., the number equals $8+2\times 2 = 12$.